# What Criteria to use in Process Builder to check for NULL reference?

Tags: process-builder, null

I have a lookup field on account - for other accounts - Name: **Account Parent Tiered OBJ**

How do I check in Process Builder that it's actually empty?

Using the `Global Constant NULL`

[image]

**or: IS Null true**

[image]

both returned the wrong answer [there always seem to be some value there]

- As debug, I tried to get the id/name/any value form the 'so called not null obj', but I get error:

**The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with**

So yea, it is NULL, but I just can't understand how to check for it.

- My process

[image]

- Error report:

> ```
>  An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1 (FlowRecordUpdate).
> The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Account_Parent_tiered_Obj__r.Name because it hasn't
> ```
>
> been set or assigned.
>
> ```
> This report lists the elements that the flow interview executed. The report is a beta feature.
> We welcome your feedback on IdeaExchange.
>
> Flow Details
> Flow Name: test_account_parent_obj
> Type: Workflow
> Version: 3
> Status: Active
>
> Flow Interview Details
> Interview Label: test_account_parent_obj-3_Account
> Current User: Saar Machtinger (00520000000vhNm)
> Start time: 12:54 11/01/2016
> Duration: 0 seconds
>
> How the Interview Started
> Saar Machtinger (00520000000vhNm) started the flow interview.
> Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
> myVariable_old = 00120000006zEWSAA2
> myVariable_current = 00120000006zEWSAA2
> RecursiveCountVariable = 0.00
>
> ASSIGNMENT: myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment
> {!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} Equals {!Flow.CurrentDateTime}
> Result
> {!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} = "12:54 11/01/2016"
>
> DECISION: isChangedDecision2_myRule_1_ParentId
> Executed this outcome: isChangedRule_2_myRule_1_ParentId
> Outcome conditions: and
> 1. {!myVariable_old} (00120000006zEWSAA2) Is null false
> 2. {!myVariable_old.ParentId} (null) Does not equal {!myVariable_current.ParentId} (00120000003rB3xAAE)
> Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)
>
> DECISION: isChangedDecision4_myRule_3_ParentId
> Executed this outcome: isChangedRule_4_myRule_3_ParentId
> Outcome conditions: and
> 1. {!myVariable_old} (00120000006zEWSAA2) Is null false
> 2. {!myVariable_old.ParentId} (null) Does not equal {!myVariable_current.ParentId} (00120000003rB3xAAE)
> Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)
>
> DECISION: myDecision
> Executed this outcome: myRule_1
> Outcome conditions: and
> 1. {!isChangedRule_2_myRule_1_ParentId} (true) Equals true
> 2. {!myVariable_current.ParentId} (00120000003rB3xAAE) Is null false
> 3. {!myVariable_current.Account_Parent_tiered_Obj__c} (null) Is null true
> Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)
> ```

NOTE: I do not have a default value on the field.

- no field udpates or flows using this field

[image]

Comment: Global constant work for me. Can you check if there is any other criteria which is failing. It will be great if you can post screenshot of your process.

Comment: @Saariko I have checked both of ways, and they are working. Are you sure that there are no another flows/triggers/processes that may handle it?

Comment: @kurunve did you check with a Lookup field? - other regular fields work fine for the checks

Comment: @Saariko yes, I have checked on lookup from account to custom and standard field

Comment: @Saariko So, that always returns you null even if that is not null?

Comment: No. There is no value in the tiered parent field. But the process criteria is not caught correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always check your conditions - and than check them again, or just rewrite the process.

My error resided in the simple solution: The condition #3 that I used, was wrong. Instead of asking for: **Account->Account_Parent_tiered_Obj__c**  - I had to filter by: **Account->Parent->Account_Parent_tiered_Obj__c**

The lesson really is to recheck your criteria.

Answer (score 11):

Try using the "Formula evaluates to true" option to check for null with the following formula:

```
[Account].Account_Parent_Tiered_OBJ__c  = null
```

Comment: This behavior kind of seems like a bug. Is this approach still the recommended one?

Comment: I think the issue turned out to be that the condition was wrong, not that the "is null" check was buggy -- see the accepted answer.

Comment: Best Practice should be ISBLANK([Account].Account_Parent_Tiered_OBJ__c). I tried = null but the rule just sneaked passed by PB rule

Answer (score 4):

I faced the exact same problem with Process Builder and then the following solution helped.

Whenever we are referring a related record in Process Builder we should put a NULL value check for that field as the first condition in filter criteria.

Then use "Customize the Logic" e.g. (1 AND 2 OR 3)
So if 1 fails the process will not go further.

Regards,
Rosh

Answer (score 4):

Well, I've just experienced a similar issue, but it's not exactly the same as yours.

In my case, the cause of the error was that I set the condition if the id of referenced record is null. I had to set if the field itself is null.

When we set the condition such as "[Parent].Child__c.Id isnull Boolean True", we'll get an error because "Child__c" is not set and the process failed to get its "Id".

So we have to set the condition like "[Parent].Child__c isnull Boolean True" instead.

This "Child__c" wasn't shown up with its label, but with its API name, so I couldn't find at the first time, but "Child(Label)>" was there. It's confusing.

Comment: is it just me, but I cant just pick "[Parent].Child__c" the builder forces me to pick a field too.